# Como consigo inserir estes caracteres em C#

Tags: c#

Como consigo inserir estes caracteres em [c#](/questions/tagged/c%23)

```
┍╍╍╍╍╍╍╍╍╍╍╍╍╍╍╍╍╍╍╍╍╍╍╍╍╍╍╍╍╍╍╍╍╍╍╍╍╍╍╍╍╍╍╍╍┑
│                                            │   
│                                            │   
│                                            │   
│                                            │   
│                                            │   
└╍╍╍╍╍╍╍╍╍╍╍╍╍╍╍╍╍╍╍╍╍╍╍╍╍╍╍╍╍╍╍╍╍╍╍╍╍╍╍╍╍╍╍╍┚
```

Queria usa-los para criar menus na consola.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Bom eu fiz um menu uma vez da seguinte maneira: 
onde

> (char) '\u2554'

você substitui de acordo com a tabela do link na Wiki

```
            string MenuDesenho = string.Empty;
            for (int i = 0; i < 36; i++) {
                MenuDesenho +=(""+(char)'\u2550');
            }
               string menu =((char)'\u2554'+MenuDesenho+(char)'\u2557'+"\n");
                menu += ((char)'\u2551' +"              Menu                  "+(char)'\u2551'+"\n");
                menu += ((char)'\u2551' +" 1. Para adicionar um Quadrado      "+(char)'\u2551'+"\n");
                menu += ((char)'\u2551' +" 2. Para adicionar um Retangulo     "+(char)'\u2551'+"\n");
                menu += ((char)'\u2551' +" 3. Para adicionar um Circulo       "+(char)'\u2551'+"\n");
                menu += ((char)'\u2551' +" 4. Para Remover uma figura         "+(char)'\u2551'+"\n");
                menu += ((char)'\u2551' +" 5. Para mostrar a lista            "+(char)'\u2551'+"\n");
                menu += ((char)'\u2551' +" 6. Para limpar todas as figuras    "+(char)'\u2551'+"\n");
                menu += ((char)'\u2551' +" 7. Para limpar a Tela              "+(char)'\u2551'+"\n");
                menu += ((char)'\u2551' +" 8. Para Sair                       "+(char)'\u2551'+"\n");
                    menu += ((char)'\u255a'+MenuDesenho+(char)'\u255d');
Console.Write(menu);
```

aqui o link para vê os código em ASCII Box

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Box-drawing_character

Neste link você pode term mais detalhado para da linguagem.

http://graphemica.com/%E2%95%93

Olha no [dotnetfiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/qebICI) como fica.

De acordo com sua imagem seria assim o código:

```
using System;


public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {

        string MenuDesenho = string.Empty;
            for (int i = 0; i <28; i++) {
                MenuDesenho +=(""+(char)'\u254D');
            }
               string menu =((char)'\u250D'+MenuDesenho+(char)'\u2511'+"\n");
                menu += ((char)'\uFFE8' +"              Menu                  "+(char)'\uFFE8'+"\n");
                menu += ((char)'\uFFE8' +" 1. Para adicionar um Quadrado      "+(char)'\uFFE8'+"\n");
                menu += ((char)'\uFFE8' +" 2. Para adicionar um Retangulo     "+(char)'\uFFE8'+"\n");
                menu += ((char)'\uFFE8' +" 3. Para adicionar um Circulo       "+(char)'\uFFE8'+"\n");
                menu += ((char)'\uFFE8' +" 4. Para Remover uma figura         "+(char)'\uFFE8'+"\n");
                menu += ((char)'\uFFE8' +" 5. Para mostrar a lista            "+(char)'\uFFE8'+"\n");
                menu += ((char)'\uFFE8' +" 6. Para limpar todas as figuras    "+(char)'\uFFE8'+"\n");
                menu += ((char)'\uFFE8' +" 7. Para limpar a Tela              "+(char)'\uFFE8'+"\n");
                menu += ((char)'\uFFE8' +" 8. Para Sair                       "+(char)'\uFFE8'+"\n");
                menu += ((char)'\u2514'+MenuDesenho+(char)'\u251A');
        Console.Write(menu);
    }
}
```

Comment: o que é o MenuDesenho?

Comment: É um For de linha reta, me desculpe achei que era o seu desenho da pergunta  arrumei já